# Mono ASP.Net MVC MissingMethod on HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, mono, system.web, missingmethodexception

I have an issue about running my ASP.Net MVC app on Mono. I got Ninject, Moq from NuGet, used them in the app and when I launched it I got MissingMethodException on HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager property's "get" method. Since I googled this exception I found out that Mono actually misses this property at all. I found implementation as well but I do not know how can I do it. I found only System.Web.dll and I do not know what can be done with this .dll - should I decompile it or what. What should I do with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer already. It can be useful for somebody else: In the Mono's git repo they fixed this bug, so I can just compile Mono from there.